# How to solve Failed to run "xelatex .\notebook.tex -quiet" command: notebook.tex:373:?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, windows-10, jupyter-lab, pdflatex, miktex

I am trying to convert my jupyterlab into pdf but I am getting this error server.

> nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
> Failed to run "xelatex .\notebook.tex -quiet" command: 
> notebook.tex:373:

and here is the code that I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{documentation}
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = x^2
\end{equation}
\end{documentation}
```

I want to precise that I have downloaded all the updates in MikTeX, and the same code when I keep only the equation part, does work fine. I also tried to change the location of \end by placing it at the end of the fist block, and it's still giving me the same error. 
PS: nbconvert: Convert Notebooks to other formats
Can anyone help please?